# "There IS/ARE an even number of rules" - What is the correct verb and what is the subject?

Tags: verbs, tenses, agreement

What is the subject in the following sentence and is the verb agreement correct?

"There is an even number of rules."

Comment: In the construction *There is an X*, the entirety of X is a noun phrase (NP) - in your example, ***an even number of rules***. If you're specifically focused on the (singular) element ***number*** within that NP, you can get away with using the singular verb form ***is*** in your *exact* context, but this would be far less likely with, for example, *An even number of people **were** invited to the party.*

Comment: The subject is "there". The verb tense is wrong -- it should be plural "are" to match the noun "rules" (cf. "There are a number of rules to be observed"). But with existential "there", and reduced "is", many speakers ignore the rule and always use the singular: "There's an even number of rules".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66517/discussion-between-black-and-white-and-araucaria).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  The problem is though that you cannot helpfully redirect readers to a question that will necessarily help them, if it only addresses half the question. And the linked to question is closed anyway. [There's also the fact that, as FF pointed out, this question is not quite the same as the linked-to one in terms of agreement, because as he says, *is* will potentially work here.]

Comment: There is also [What is the difference between these two almost identical sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154586/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-almost-identical-sentences/154686#154686). ELU needs to be as concise as possible (no bloat) to really be of use to as many as possible. / Note also that FF and BillJ disagree, and that neither adds a source endorsing what they say.